# No encuentra directorio en python 3 por contener una letra Ñ

Tags: python

Al intentar abrir un archivo que se encuentra en el siguiente directorio en un Jupyter notebook:

`os.chdir('C:/CARRERA/AÑO 2023/PYTHON')`

Me sale el siguiente error y buscando soluciones por internet no encuentro ninguna que me lo solucione. Parece que está leyendo el caracter Ñ en otro formato.

*WindowsError: [Error 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'C:/CARRERA/A\xc3\x91O 2023/PYTHON'*

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Víctor, bienvenido,  puede ser que ese sea el problema, pero me inclino a pensar que no, siendo que estás en la fea "W", la ruta debería ser: **'C:\CARRERA\AÑO 2023\PYTHON'**, ya que "W" usa como separador de directorios la barra invertida, otro problema puede ser que la ruta tiene un espacio en blanco, eso en algunos SO y/o aplicaciones, da problemas, te sugiero que lo modifiques. Para estar seguro, prueba cambiando la "Ñ" por "N", si el problema sigue, quita el espacio en blanco, y si sigue cambia la ruta con las barras invertidas.

Comment: Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Parece que estás usando Python 2.7. En Python 3.x el chdir funciona correctamente.

Comment: @CandidMoe, tengo la versión 3.6.5 de Python

Comment: @MarcePuente, sigue dando el mismo error cambiando el separador.

Comment: Capáz que tu editor está configurado para ejecutar el Python 2.7. De casualidad tenes Python 2.7 instalado?

Comment: Victor, si ya probaste con, eliminar el espacio en blanco, cambiar el separador, y cambiar la "Ñ" por "N" y no funciona, quiere decir que el archivo no está en esa ruta, podrías mostrarnos tu directorio?